# OpenCV: how to use opencv_createsamples and opencv_traincascade

Tags: ios, opencv, detection, opencv3.0

In my project I need to recognize euro coins and someone advised me to use OpenCV classifiers and training algorithms. So I downloaded the 3.1 version of OpenCV and I trying to get it started. I would like to know some things that I don't understand from tutorials (the ones I am following are [this](http://codeyarns.com/2014/09/01/how-to-train-opencv-cascade-classifier/), [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) from OpenCV official documentation and [this](http://www.memememememememe.me/training-haar-cascades/)).

First of all, is it mandatory to generate and consider negative samples? if yes, which kind of "objects" should I consider as negatives? In my app I should detect and recognize euro coins so...should I create negatives from any other random kind of objects?

Secondly, my app is supposed to recognize 2€, 1€ and 0.50€ coins. So, how many positive samples shall I generate with `opencv_createsamples`? One for each coin (front and back) or an unique one for all the 3 kind of coins? If I have understood well, then I will have some .xml files which I am supposed to enclose in my iOS app project, right?

Finally, will `detectMultiScale()` not only detect the coin but also its kind? That's why I was thinking that I would need more than a classifier file, to distinguish back from right side and to distinguish the value of the coin.

Hoping I have not written a too broad question, thank you for your attention.

Comment: I think negative samples are must. I'm not familiar with Euro coins but it's unlikely that `detectMultiScale()` can recognize coin types, even you train them separately and use 3 different detector -- they are just to similar in shapes (round?). For that task, you would need to train an object recognition.

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you for your answer. Yes, all euro coins are round and so very similar. Ehm, what is exactly an object recognition? Can you link me a good tutorial?

Comment: It's something similar to face recognition. Usually you need to train a classification machine, be it PCA, SVM, or Neural Network. OpenCV has [face recogintion](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html), which might be used with your coin data set. -- Also note that they do have a machine learning module with more general implementations of the common classifiers.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. At this point I'm afraid I'll give up because I have never done either computer vision or image processing or machine learning. I was trying to learn something simple on my own for my thesis but I'm afraid is something too difficult to get in such little time...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding negative (or, background) example consider on which background the euro coins will be in the image that your program has to process in the end. E.g., if they are on a table together with non-Euros, use table tops (without coins) as negatives. If you want to spot them on images where people hold them, use hands as negatives, etc.

Regarding the second question - I am also searching for advice on this. I guess it depends on the complexity of the features you need to recognize and also on the complexity of the background. I succeeded to train a classifier with 40 circle positives, but completely failed to train a classifier using 60 (aerial) cow images.

Regarding your third question, I think (not tested!) that depends on your recognition needs: If you just want to spot one of the Euro coins, you'll be fine to train one classifier with images from all coins from all sides. If you want to distinguish the coins, create different classifiers with images of each coin from all sides. If you even need to distinguish front from back, you'll have to create one classifier for every side of every coin.

Answer (score 0):

yes, Negative samples are mandatory and again yes, you can have images of random objects but you need to have lots of them so i suggest use videos to extract their frames or website such as [this](http://www.image-net.org/)

next, you need to have positive samples for your coins. Greater the number of positive coins, more accurate results will be. One thing you can do is to take 2-3 images of your coin and super impose them on your negative ones by changing an angle every time you superimpose. That way if you have say, 500 negative images and 2 positive images of a coin, you will have 1000 positive images after superimposing. opencv_createsamples script takes care of all of this.